# normalize row based on condition in for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to normalize every value in a column in my csv file based on condition that normalization it's applied for each row after the first duplicate (according to rule) some kind of restarting loop.

i tried some for/while loop but i'm stuck with logic of this.

i tried :

```
temp_var = 0
 for row in csvfile : 
   if row[1] == row[2] :
       temp_var += row[3]
         row[3] = 100
        while row[1] == row[2] :
           continue
```

more precisely i have some "duplicate" when row[1] = row[2] i want to pass row[3] = 100, then i want normalise like  (row[3] of next row * 100 / row[3] true value of current row) that for every next row until the next "duplicate" and repeat.

example :

```
a | b | c
a   a   400
b   d   200
c   x   300
d   d   50
e   z   5
f    e   15
g   p   5000
```

so there's two duplicate aa / dd
i want :

```
a a 100
b d 200 * 100 /400
c x 300 * 100 / 400
d d 100
e z 5 * 100 / 50
f e 15 * 100 / 50
g p 5000 * 100 / 50
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
last_dup = None
res = []
for row in csvfile:
    if row[1] == row[2]:
        last_dup = row[3]
        row[3] = 100
    elif last_dup:
       row[3] *= 100/last_dup
    res.append(row)
```

Additional example for topic starter:

```
last_dup = None
res = []
src = [
    ["a", "a", 400],
    ["b", "d", 200],
    ["c", "x", 300],
    ["d", "d", 50],
    ["e", "z", 5],
    ["f", "e", 15],
    ["g", "p", 5000],
]
for row in src:
    if row[0] == row[1]:
        last_dup = row[2]
        row[2] = 100
    elif last_dup:
        row[2] *= 100 / last_dup
    res.append(row)
print(res)
```

```
[['a', 'a', 100], ['b', 'd', 50.0], ['c', 'x', 75.0], ['d', 'd', 100], ['e', 'z', 10.0], ['f', 'e', 30.0], ['g', 'p', 10000.0]]
```

Comment: It returns empty string after duplicate

Comment: @user9176398 i can't reproduce your problem :)